# Exclude specific words from being saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a title attribute for my Photo model. I do not want users to add words such as ... picture, Print, photo, image, photograph, pic

I have this validation in place but it doesn't seem to be picking it up when trying to create/update a title

validates :title, exclusion: { within: %w(picture, Print, photo, image, photograph, pic),

I tried it with :in as well

validates :title, exclusion: { in: %w(picture, Print, photo, image, photograph, pic)

Any ideas as to why a title like 'Chicago skyline photo' would be saved to the db?

Answer (score 1):

Exclusion will catch "photo" but not "skyline photo" nor "Chicago skyline photo"... it checks the entire attribute only.

You'd be better off with a custom validation.

```
validate :reject_if_includes_image_words

def reject_if_includes_image_words
  title.split(' ').each do |word|
    if %w(picture print photo image photograph pic).include? word.downcase
      errors.add(:title, "can't include the word '#{word}'")
      break
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT

To handle the case of punctuation or digits and to include @pdobb's excellent suggestion...

```
IMAGE_WORDS = %w(picture print photo image photograph pic)

validate :reject_if_includes_image_words

def reject_if_includes_image_words
  used_image_words = title.gsub(/[^A-Za-z\s]/,'').split & IMAGE_WORDS
  errors.add(:title, "can't use '#{used_image_words.join('\', \'')}'") if used_image_words.any?
end
```

Comment: Might save a few ticks to use array intersection. Plus can then include all invalid words in the error message: `invalid_words = %w(picture print photo image photograph pic) & "asdf picture and pic".split` then `errors.add(:title, "can't include the word(s): #{invalid_words.join(', ')}") if invalid_words.any?`. Would also be ideal to move the image words list into a constant.

Comment: How could I modify that function to not include numbers or parenthesis?

Comment: Hi, see the edit, it now ignores numbers or punctuation and incorporates great suggestion made by @pdobb . Cheers